# How to get the counts of logs per day in a week through the logging or monitoring API?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

My logs are stored in Google cloud logging. I need to record the exact number of daily logs under specified conditions, generate a line graph, and apply to my website.

This are the line chart and stacked bar chart I tried to generate in metrics explorer, but I can't understand them.

[line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1wlo.png)
[stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnsoX.png)

Below is my log records:
[log records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lADKz.png)
As you can see, the number of logs on the 15th was 7,but it seems that there is no way to show it in the chart,is my setting wrong?
Thanks